# Same expression but different derivatives

Tags: complex, calculus-and-analysis

Consider this expression

```
VexpansRI = Conjugate[ A + (I dI + dR + vd/Sqrt[2]) (I sI + sR + vs/Sqrt[2]) (I uI + uR + vu/Sqrt[2])]
```

Now since

```
FullSimplify[Conjugate[x y]==Conjugate[x] Conjugate[y]]  
FullSimplify[Conjugate[x + y]==Conjugate[x] + Conjugate[y]]  
(*  True  *)
(*  True  *)
```

we can apply these rules

```
ConjRules = {  
   Conjugate[x_ y_] :> Conjugate[x] Conjugate[y],  
   Conjugate[x_ + y_] :> Conjugate[x] + Conjugate[y]  
   };
```

so define

```
VexpansRI1 = Simplify[VexpansRI //.ConjRules]
```

Calculating

```
FullSimplify[VexpansRI - VexpansRI1]
```

we obtain `0`, so that `VexpansRI == VexpansRI1`

But calculating the derivatives

```
DV = D[VexpansRI, uR, dR];  
DV1 = D[VexpansRI1, uR, dR];  
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[FullSimplify[ DV - DV1 ]]]
```

we obtain

```
2 I sI
```

Since the expressions `VexpansRI` is equal to `VexpansRI1`, why we get different derivatives?

Thank you

Comment: Using `ComplexExpand` without specifying which variables are complex will cause all variables to be treated as `Reals`. Also, Mathematica cannot take the derivative of `Conjugate`, you need to express the complex variables in  an explicit complex form. e.g., `x + I*y` then use `ComplexExpand` which will remove `Conjugate`. Then derivatives can be taken.

Comment: @ Bob Hi Bob, thanks for your reply.

Regarding ComplexExpand my point is that also assuming all the variables are reals (as ComplExpand do) the difference is no zero, as should be. Of course, if you don't use ComplexExpand, you get a longer result, again not zero.    

When you say that Mathematica cannot take the derivative of Conjugate, what do you mean?
I see it treats Conjugate as a function and apply the chain rule. After that, with ComplexExpand it can manage the derivative of Conjugate.

Comment: Anyway, my problem is that since we start with one expression expressed in 2 different equivalent ways, that is VexpansRI and VexpansRI1, calculating derivative I expect the same result. Why Mathematica gives different results?

Comment: Using `Conjugate` then at least some variables are complex. Consequently, you need to specify which ones are by using second argument. "ComplexExpand[expr, {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], ...}] expands expr assuming that variables matching any of the Subscript[x, i] are complex." You may also want/need to use the option `TargetFunctions` to get a useful form. `Conjugate` is not differentiable. Under `Possible Issues` for `Conjugate`: "Differentiating Conjugate is not possible.", i.e., `Conjugate'[x]` is undefined. You cannot compare results of improperly used & undefined functions.